# Inconsistent text rendering between iOS and Mac

Tags: ios, css, fonts, safari, text-rendering

iOS 8 Safari (Retina) vs Mac OS X Yosemite Safari (Retina)

[image: screenshot]

The one on the Mac is the desired rendering i.e. kerning and ligatures. The one on iOS seems too loose (this is Simulator, looks the same on device). The font is Lato served from Google.

Any way to make the text on iOS look as good as on the Mac?

**UPDATE**

Seems like it could be a problem with Lato. I tried different fonts i.e. Proxima Nova and they looked the same on iOS and Mac OS, despite not having ligatures. I also can't get iOS to render ligatures in Lato no matter what. This is my CSS.

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Use Typekit instead of Google font.

[image]

You get what you pay for.

Here's the code which did the trick.

```
<script>
    WebFontConfig = {
      typekit: { id: 'xzw9acq' } // Typekit kit containing Lato
      //google: { families: ['Lato'] }
    };
    ... rest of font loader script
  </script>
```

Comment: If you could add the code or settings that fixed your problem then this will help future people having the same problem.